# How to search for all sites on sharepoint but exclude all personal sites using rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-server

I am using the REST API to search through SharePoint using the call:

```
_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site'&rowlimit=1000&startrow=0
```

but I am also getting all the personal sites and links to OneDrive folders.

How can I exclude them from using this REST API search query for both SharePoint online and on-premise?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a path filter in your REST API endpoint.

Normal site collections have a path like `https://tenant.sharepoint.com` whereas personal (One Drive) site collections have path like `https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/*`.

So, you can modify your endpoint as below:

```
https://<site_name>.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site Path:"https://<site_name>.sharepoint.com/*"'&rowlimit=1000
```

This will only return site collections starting with `https://<site_name>.sharepoint.com` path and will exclude the One Drive site collections which are on a different path.

Comment: It is still returning personal sites with the path https://<sitename>.sharepoint.com/portals/personal/<user name>