# How to get list of all personal sites using SharePoint API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-rest-api, my-site

Is there a way to get a list of all personal sites using SharePoint API's?

I referred to [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/281462/how-to-search-for-all-sites-on-sharepoint-but-exclude-all-personal-sites-using-r) answer to get all the personal sites and used:

```
https://abc.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site Path:"https://abc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/*"'
```

But this does not give the personal sites.

Answer (score 0):

The personal site collection have path **"https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/"**.

You can use below REST API query to get a list of all personal sites.

```
https://<site_name>.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site Path:"https://<site_name>-my.sharepoint.com"'
```

For ex- **"personalsite-my.sharepoint.com"** is my site collection.In order to get list of all personal sites you can use query -

```
http://personalsite.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:"https://personalsite-my.sharepoint.com contentclass:STS_Site"'
```

You may be comfortable writing REST API calls to achieve this. Alternatively, I would highly recommend using the SharePoint 2013 Search tool to help out.